PhD supervisor does not support
I am a recent university graduate with a master's in engineering. After graduation, I landed a job, and my supervisor encouraged me to apply for a PhD, promising to provide funding. I applied and started my PhD, and now I am in my second semester. However, he has not provided any funding or assigned me a project. What should I do? I am considering dropping out of the program, but I was awarded a merit-based scholarship that doesn’t allow me to do so. It would also reflect poorly on the university if I were to drop out. ( Please note I applied myself to this scholarship and got it based on my overall gpa)

Does your scholarship come with a stipend? It would be unusual (at least in the US where I am most familiar) to have additional funding on top of whatever is considered "full support". Have you spoken to your advisor about projects, or are you just waiting for them to reach out? Do you talk about research at all?

When you say they have not assigned a project, do you mean you don't have a fixed thesis topic yet, or you have not been involved in any research yet? I typically do not firm up the thesis topic of my students until their 3rd-4th semester. The first few are for training, building up a knowledge base, getting familiar with lab projects, etc...

I don’t understand how the individual pieces fit together here. You say you "landed a job" but is this in or outside of academia? The supervisor of that job, are they an academic and/or affiliated with any academic institution? If you already have a job, why does the supervisor of the job need to provide additional funding? If you have a scholarship , why do you need additional funding? Why doesn’t the scholarship allow you to drop out - what is the penalty for doing so?

Separately, did you actually talk to your supervisor about any of this?

@BryanKrause, one year support from university, it is for the scholarship that I applied. The duration of support is one year only.

@nikki Then I wouldn't expect your direct supervisor to fund your position until next semester. Do you mean that there is currently no plan for you for funding then? How are you sure that there is no such plan? What does your advisor say when you ask them about this plan?

A scholarship that "doesn't allow you to drop out"? This seems unlikely. I mean, how will they stop you? ;-)

It is a chancellor fellowship which was given to me. It is a one year scholarship. It has lots of responsibilities and university advertisement which features me. Basically I was chosen based on my GPA and work among lots of students

I suggest two things. First, don't concern yourself with how it reflects on the university or others, but only on your own career and educational goals.
Second, you need to have a face to face talk with the advisor about your future. Remind them that you need funding (or will) and that you need to come to an agreement soonest about a project. The current situation is untenable and unsustainable and helpful for no-one.
Depending on their response, you can then decide whether to go elsewhere. If they are less than fully supportive, I'd start looking at other options.
